# mvc3, can you give controller a display name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using mvc3. is it possible to give controller and action a display name.

```
[DisplayName("Facebook Employee")]
public class EmployeeController : Controller
```

in my breadcrumb, I will get the controller name and action name

```
@{
var controllerName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
var actionName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"];
}
```

I expect to see "Facebook Employee", but its not working.

Comment: Why you just set a title? and called the title in the view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to reflect on the Controller type itself, using [`GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx).  Use `ViewContext.Controller` to get a reference to the controller itself.  Something like this:

```
string controllerName;
Type type = ViewContext.Controller.GetType();
var atts = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false);
if (atts.Length > 0)
    controllerName = ((DisplayNameAttribute)atts[0]).DisplayName;
else 
    controllerName = type.Name;   // fallback to the type name of the controller
```

**Edit**

To do similar for an action, you need to first reflect on the method, using `Type.GetMethodInfo`:

```
string actionName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(actionName);
var atts = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false);
// etc, same as above
```

Comment: thank you so much, It try do the same to get action display name.  ViewContext.Action.GetType(), its not working. how do i get current action type?

Comment: @feelexit it's slightly different for an Action -- see update above.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static class HLP
      {

  public static string DisplayNameController(this WebViewPage wvp)
    {
        if (wvp.ViewBag.Title != null && (wvp.ViewBag.Title as string).Trim().Length > 0)
            return wvp.ViewBag.Title;

        ControllerBase Controller = wvp.ViewContext.Controller;
        try
        {
            DisplayNameAttribute[] attr = (DisplayNameAttribute[])Controller.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false);
            string DisplayName = attr[0].DisplayName; 

            return DisplayName;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Controller.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string DisplayNameAction(this WebViewPage wvp)
    {
        string actionName = wvp.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString();

        try
        {
            Type type = wvp.ViewContext.Controller.GetType();
            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(actionName); 

            DisplayNameAttribute[] attr = (DisplayNameAttribute[])method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false);
            string DisplayName = attr[0].DisplayName; 
            return DisplayName;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return actionName;
        }

    }
}



 <title>@this.DisplayNameAction()</title>
```