# How to bypass [SessionExpire] attribute on a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to bypass my [SessionExpire] that has redirection to login. 
I want to bypass the attribute to execute it without logging in.

A custom attribute as shown :

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            // check  sessions here
            if( HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] == null ) 
            {
               filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
               return;
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }

//SAMPLE IMPLEMENTATION:


[SessionExpire]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     return Index();
  }
//I WANT TO BYPASS THIS JSONRESULT WITHOUT GOING TO SESSIONEXPIRE
  public JsonResult Result()
  {

     return Json();
  }

}
```

Comment: When do you want to do that? Always? If so, maybe adjust your timeout?

Comment: @Jonathan I added some information to the question sir, I just want to execute a jsonresult without going to the login.

Comment: You could put the attributes onto the specific controller methods that you want to use them, instead of on the whole controller class

Comment: @Jonathan Yeah, thats my last resort because inside my controller i got 20 of classes to put separate [sessionexpire].

Comment: @Jonathan you deleted your answer. It is working and i added 'else' from your code. Searched it and gave the link to the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: I deleted it because when I looked at it again, I thought it was unlikely to work. I thought it would call the attribute method twice; once for method and once for class. I'll re add my answer. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this would work, but what if you put an extra property in there, and then pass through data on the *one* method that's the exception? Something like:

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public bool IsIgnore {get;set;}

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (IsIgnore)
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        // check  sessions here
        if( HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] == null ) 
        {
           filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
           return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

//SAMPLE IMPLEMENTATION:


[SessionExpire]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
   return Index();
  }
//I WANT TO BYPASS THIS JSONRESULT WITHOUT GOING TO SESSIONEXPIRE
  [SessionExpire(IsIgnore = true)]
  public JsonResult Result()
  {
     return Json();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Jonathan:

Passing custom parameter in custom attribute.
Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770432/passing-custom-parameter-in-custom-attribute-asp-net-mvc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is check if user is authenticated but in a rather custom way. Official documentation is rather extended, so I'd recommend to read 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-2.2 .

With your case I'd recommend to implement [IAuthorizationFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) and use [AllowAonymousAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.allowanonymousattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2). to bypass authentication.

Also you could improve UX by redirect user back to the page which it tried to access before authentication. For example if user tried to navigate to `/orders` but he was not authenticated, he is redirected to `/account/login` and once he is authenticated he should go back to `/orders` automatically. You can use a parameter for that: `/account/login?redirect=orders`